# Can I have .cpp file for an abstract class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I've got an abstract class (header file) and I want to implement its non virtual functions.
Currently the implementation written at the header file, but I feel like there's too much code there for header file.
Can I have .cpp file implementing its functions?

Comment: Don't let the "abstract" scare you. It's a class like any other. It just has a small constraint on any object of that type you may want to create.

Comment: What makes you think you cannot?

Comment: just asking to be sure :) thanks!

Comment: afaik you can even provide a definition for pure abstract methods, though i never understood what that would be good for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, header files (`.h`, `.hpp`, *etc*) are `#include`'d in `.cpp` files by simply copying it's contents into the `.cpp` file. Copy-'n-pasting the header file where the `#include` is wouldn't change the compilation.